# using a module exported from browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a simple node.js project where I ran the following commands:

```
npm init
npm install buffer --save
browserify -r buffer -o buffer.js
```

How can I require that buffer.js file into other files or projects, and actually use the Buffer classed contained within it?

I have tried

```
var Buffer = require('./buffer.js');
var x = new Buffer();
```

but I get `TypeError: Buffer is not a constructor`

What am I doing wrong to be able to use that node module from another location?

Comment: Browserify is for client side projects, you shouldn't be using with server side code. Just require `buffer` directly.

Comment: I am not trying to use it in a client side project, so I am trying to see if I can make this work somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a UMD bundle with the [`-s` flag](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage):

```
browserify -r buffer -o buffer.js -s buffer
```

And then fix the file in which you require it:

```
var Buffer = require('./buffer').Buffer;

var x = new Buffer('some content');
```